# Where is the MockProcessorContext for unit testing FixedKeyProcessors in Kafka Streams?

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-kafka-streams

It's been a year or two since I've written Streams apps, and I see that some API cleanup has happened, notably here, that ValueTransformers have been deprecated in favor of FixedKeyProcessors. But searching around, I've not found the magic class that would perform like the other MockProcessorContexts (used in Processor or Transformer). Am I supposed to mockito my own here? Or can I use a richer mock from the library? (I'm using version 3.5.0)

Answer (score 0):

There are some subclasses of `MockProcessorContext` that implemented the `FixedKeyProcessorContext`, such as `MockInternalProcessorContext`. See if it suits your needs.